# PM2 cron process restarting too many times, not every 15 minutes

Tags: cron, pm2

I'm using pm2 to run a script every 15 minutes, or at least I'm trying. The code I used to start the process and keep it restarting is the on that follows:

```sh
pm2 start dist/scripts/updatePowerDemandGeneration.js --name script-UpdatePowerDemandGeneration --cron "*/15 * * * *" --log /home/lkuratani/projects/prisma-logs/updatePowerGeneration.log
```

I cleaned the logs file, and this is what I got after some minutes:

```
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:18:51 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:19:13 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:19:15 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:19:48 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:20:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:20:27 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:20:47 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:20:49 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:21:07 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:21:10 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:21:29 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:21:31 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:21:50 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:21:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:22:11 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:22:13 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:22:33 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:22:34 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:22:53 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:22:55 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:23:15 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:23:16 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:23:35 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:23:37 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:23:56 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:23:58 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:24:18 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:24:20 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:24:39 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:24:41 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:25:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:25:02 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:25:21 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:25:23 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:25:42 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:25:44 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:26:03 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:26:05 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:26:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:26:26 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:26:46 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:26:47 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Finished Tue Nov 17 2020 14:27:07 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Started Tue Nov 17 2020 14:27:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

I logged the date with:

```js
console.log(`Started ${new Date().toString()}`)
// code
console.log(`Finished ${new Date().toString()}`)
```

I can't seem to know what's happening, the process restarts after some seconds, not 15 minutes. I'm using PM2 as root. To generate this cron string, I used this website: [Crontab.guru][1]

*[1]: https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_**